# dataframe doesnot read my generated csv file correctly (just one column float64)

Tags: python

Temperature from a log file (in text format) is extracted then is written to a newly created temp.CSV file.  "C" is removed from number.  Below is the table that shows data in original text.  Then in CSV using excel to open, then  CSV using Notepad++ to open.  And finally read into dataframe which shows nothing (or NaN when print).

| Original w/ notepad++ | (In CSV) | CSV w/ Notepad++ | CSV read in dataframe |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Temp: 33.75C | 33.75 | " NUL 33.75" |  |
| Temp: 33.55C | 33.55 | " NUL 33.55" |  |

When read into dataframe, every is correct, except this temperature column which shows nothing, and which when print (while running) shows NaN.  The number is of float64 datatype.  So formatting this column to something such as "{:.2f}".format()  does not work.  Strangely, if this temp.csv is open, then SAVE again without any modification (must be SAVE, not just close).  Then the dataframe read will be correct.

Thanks for looking into this. (btw, I'm using python3.7)

lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
`line = line.replace( "[", " " )  # no bracket`
`line = line.replace( "NUL", " " )  # no parenthesis`

Comment: My GUESS is that you have special characters in your log file (note the "NUL" symbol) that prevents pandas from seeing it as a number.  How exactly are you converting the original file to get rid of the text?

Comment: Please share the log file so we can have a look.

Comment: Thanks Tim for answering this.   Below is what I did from the text file:         lines = f.readlines()  # will return a list containing lines ['line1\n', 'line2\n'...]
        for line in lines:  # start with first line.  And evaluate each line at a time.
            line = line.replace( "[", " " )  # no bracket
            line = line.replace( "]", " " )  # no bracket
            line = line.replace( "(", " " )  # no parenthesis
            line = line.replace( ")", " " )  # no parenthesis
            line = line.replace( "NUL", " " )  # no parenthesis

Comment: Hi Tim,  if you cannot read what I copy/paste from python, I can do again.  I dont know why all the lines are crumble together.

Comment: Thanks Balderman.  I dont know how to attach a text file here.

Comment: Thanks gents especially Tim.

Comment: I didnot take care of the Nul character properly.  I used line=line.replace("Nul", " ")  which didnot work. It should be line.replace("\00", "").   But your comment made me focus on that instead of wandering somewhere else.   Thanks.  Doug